# Execute fn(param1, param2) in callback AngularJS ng-click style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, q

In AngularJS (and i'm pretty sure I have seen it elsewhere) you pass in a function with params to ng-click. ie

```
<div ng-click="myFunc(param)">Click Me</div>
```

What I want to do is pass a function with params like that as a callback in JS. Ie.

```
setTimeout(myFunc(param), 2000);
```

I figure it must be possible as Angular seems to pull it off, but can find it anywhere.

---

PS. the use case for this is creating a setTimeout that works with promises so I can return it in a promise chain. in case you are interested this is where I am stuck:

```
function qTimeout(fn, duration){
  var deferred = q.defer();

  setTimeout(function () {
    fn(*grr*)
      .then(deferred.resolve)
      .catch(deferred.reject)
  })

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Use the `$timeout` service. It wraps `setTimeout`, returns a promise and can be chained. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg what I was trying to do was replicate the functionality in NodeJS, I was just sure that I had seen it working in Angular before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to find out is Closure?

```
function myFunc(param) {
  return function myFunc2() {
    // do something with param..
    return doAsync(param); // suppose to return promise 
  };
}

setTimeout(myFunc(param), 2000);
```

`myFunc` will return `myFunc2` which have `param` from `myFunc` and `myFunc2` is going to be executed in `setTimeout` after 2000ms.

Comment: Yep, that was what I was looking for! I have heard of closures but never looked into them. Cheers!